# Не работает php + ajax post, в чем причина ошибки и статуса Pending?

Tags: php, ajax

```
<div class="form">
    <div class="left-block">
        <div class="input required name"><input type="text" name="name" required="required" placeholder="Введите имя"></div>
        <div class="input required phone"><input type="text" name="phone" required="required" placeholder="Введите телефон"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-block">
        <div class="input email"><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Введите E-Mail"></div>
        <div class="input city"><input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Введите город"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-block">
        <div id="dropdown-menu" class="dropdown-menu">
            <span class="title">Выберите услугу</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a>test</a></li>
                <li><a>test</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <button class="green-btn">ОТПРАВИТЬ</button>
    </div>
</div>

/////////////////////////js////////////////////////////////////////
    <script>
    $('.pop-up .pop-up-win .green-btn').click(function () {
            var name = $('.pop-up .pop-up-win input[name="name"]'),
                phone = $('.pop-up .pop-up-win input[name="phone"]'),
                email = $('.pop-up .pop-up-win input[name="email"]'),
                city = $('.pop-up .pop-up-win input[name="city"]'),
                service = $('.dropdown-menu .title').html();

            if (name.val().length < 3) {
                error_input(name);
                return;
            }

            if (phone.val().length < 9) {
                error_input(phone);
                return;
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'php/send-order.php',
                data: {
                    name: name.val(),
                    phone: phone.val(),
                    email: email.val(),
                    city: city.val(),
                    service: service
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('.pop-up .pop-up-win>.title').html('Заявка отправлена! <span style="display: block;">Наш менеджер свяжется с Вами в ближайшее время</span>')
                    $('.pop-up .pop-up-win .form').hide();
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

////////////////////php///////////////////////


   <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])      ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])     ||
   empty($_POST['email'])     ||
   empty($_POST['city'])     ||
   empty($_POST['service'])   ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
   echo "No arguments Provided!";
   return false;
   }

$name = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']));
$phone = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['phone']));
$email_address = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']));
$city = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['city']));
$service = strip_tags(htmlspecialchars($_POST['service']));

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'kz.marketcity.kz@gmail.com'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\ncity: $city\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$service";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address";   
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;         
?>
```

Почему форма не работает и статус стоит pending в Network??? [image: Вот запрос]

Comment: dataType:'json', поставь, ну и проверь приходит в $_POST что то или нет?

Comment: Дата собирается нормально @dpi

Comment: а ты на локальном сервере у себя дома почту отправить хочешь?? Если да то нужно настраивать почтовый сервер. Если в $_POST все данные есть то все заработает можешь выливать.

Comment: сделай в php файле var_dump($name) и всех других переменный  приходят переменные?

Comment: Да все приходит это с сайта test.fcompany.kz

Comment: тогда лайкни мой ответ))

Comment: Да нет же говорю рабочий домен сервер) можешь перейти посмотреть)

Comment: А путь к файлу php/send-order.php прописан правильно? 

попробуй телефон и прочее задать явно  

url: 'правильный путь к файлу.php',

в php 
    $name = isset($_POST['name'])?mb_substr(htmlspecialchars(trim(strip_tags($_POST['name']))), 0,50,'UTF-8'):'';

Comment: Да не извини вообще не в этом причина) спасибо большое

Comment: ну а в чем?? ты разобрался ?